# Get Value of ListView Item on selectedIndexChanged on Dropdownlist in ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, drop-down-menu

I have a ListView and DropDownList in every Row of that ListView. You can cahnge a assigned person in that DropDownlist (the DropDownList shows Data from a MySql Database).

When changing the person I need to do some database operation. For that I need to know on which ListView Row the person was changed and I need to know the value of the entry.

Here is my aspx-file:

```
<asp:ListView ID="manageAssigneesListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="" OnItemDataBound="OnDataBound">            
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="summaryRow">
                        <asp:Label ID="customerId" runat="server"><%# Eval("customerId") %>&nbsp;</asp:Label>    
                        <div style="width:200px; margin: 0px 5px; float: left;"><%# Eval("lastName") %>, <%# Eval("firstName") %></div>
                        <div style="width:120px; margin: 0px 2px; float: left;">Nr.</div>
                        <div style="width:200px; margin-left: 50px; float: right;">
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="selectAssignee" Width="196" AppendDataBoundItems="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="selectAssignee_OnSelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Here is my codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Helper.doAuth(Session, Response);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // load all customers without assignee
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = Helper.CONNECTION_STRING;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT customerId, lastName, firstName, assignee FROM customer WHERE assignee IS NULL ORDER BY customerId DESC";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);
            manageAssigneesListView.DataSource = ds;
            manageAssigneesListView.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }
    }

    protected void OnDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList selectAssignee = (e.Item.FindControl("selectAssignee") as DropDownList);

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = Helper.CONNECTION_STRING;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM user where role = " + Helper.ROLE_SALESPERSON;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        selectAssignee.DataSource = ds;
        selectAssignee.DataTextField = "emailAdress";
        selectAssignee.DataBind();
        con.Close();    
    }


    protected void selectAssignee_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;
        ListViewItem listView = (ListViewItem)dropDownList.NamingContainer;

        var test = listView.DataItem;
        string test2 = listView.FindControl("customerId").ToString();

        int rowIndex = (int)listView.DataItemIndex;
        Label lblMessage = (Label)listView.FindControl("customerId");
    }
```

I was successful getting the DataItemIndex of the Row I changed the value of the DropDownList, also the DropDownlist is firing correcty onSelectedIndexChanged, but what I need is the value of the Label "customerId" and I don't know how to get this value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `FindControl` to get the reference to the `Label`, then use it's Text property:

```
ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)dropDownList.NamingContainer;
Label lbltCustomerID = (Label) item.FindControl("customerId");
string customerID = lblCustomerID.Text;
```

By the way, the `ListViewItem.DataItem` is always `null` on postbacks.

**Edit**:

You should set the `Text` of the label, so instead of

```
<asp:Label ID="customerId" runat="server">
    <%# Eval("customerId") %>&nbsp;
</asp:Label>
```

this

```
<asp:Label ID="customerId" runat="server"
   Text='<%# Eval("customerId") %>' >
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I did use FindControl in almost exact the same way you did. String customerID is still empty.

Comment: @user1814545: Set the `Text` property instead. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. With the text-property your solution is perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

try to get the value of the label directly from the ListView like

```
        DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;
        ListViewItem listView = (ListViewItem)dropDownList.NamingContainer;

        var test = listView.DataItem;
        string test2 = listView.FindControl("customerId").ToString();

        int rowIndex = (int)listView.DataItemIndex;
        Label label = (Label)manageAssigneesListView.Items[rowIndex ].Controls[0];
```

or

```
 Label label = (Label)manageAssigneesListView.Items[rowIndex].FindControl("customerId");
```

and make sure that the ListView doesn't bind everytime on postback

like if the ListView loaded on PageLoad don't forget to add it in :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      //Load ListView
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's answered my solution worked great for me:

```
protected void myDdl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList dropDownList = (DropDownList)sender;
        ListViewDataItem listView = (ListViewDataItem)dropDownList.NamingContainer;
        int rowIndex = listView.DataItemIndex;
        //Some logic
    }
```

Not that i use ListViewDataItem instread of Peasmaker's solution